# How do you continue a sentence with a command inside

Tags: bash, scripting

For example, I have been trying to say "There are 10 people online at the moment" in my script file.

I can never seem to get the command working without the "people online at the moment" part on the next line.

At the moment, I have

```
w='who | wc -l' 
echo "There are $w people online at the moment"
```

However, I always end up with the output

```
There are who | wc -l users online at the moment
```

How do you get the command working in the middle? 
I've been trying to look and copy examples, but it doesn't seem to help my command substitution issue.

Answer (score 20):

You want the output of

```
who | wc -l
```

assigned to `w`, not that string, which is what you get because of the quotes around it. You should use command substitution `$(...)`:

```
w=$(who | wc -l)
echo "There are $w people online at the moment"
```

(you can also use the backquotes, but you cannot easily nest those).

Comment: In some shells, including Bash, you can nest backquotes.  It requires nested escapes, see example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2657037/776723

Comment: @Polyergic Thanks. I updated my answer, but I think I will stick with nesting `$()` myself ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Another solution:

`echo There are $(who | wc -l) people online at the moment`

Answer (score 6):

you should use backtick to execute command

`` w=`who | wc -l` 
echo "There are $w people online at the moment" ``

Comment: See why [`$(...)` is preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)...

Comment: Valid point. "The backtick is also easily confused with a single quote." exactly what happened here.

Comment: @Ghanima: Indeed! This question is a great example for when we need to demonstrate why backticks should be avoided. :)

Comment: Good, I've upvoted only this answer because it's the only one which explained exactly _where_ the OP had the mistake. Whether backticks are good or evil are just side notes.