# What is $PWD? (vs current working directory)

Tags: environment-variables, terminology

So Wikipedia ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PWD)) tells me that the command `pwd` is short for "print working directory", and that makes sense.

But for the environment variable, the "P" has to be an acronym for something else than print.

I hear people talking about "current working directory", which sounds better and is more intuitive, but still the environment variable seems to be called $PWD, and not $CWD. Nobody ever says "Did you check the print working directory variable?".

I am currently playing around with the web application server uWSGI, and when running it tells me (on the uWSGI stats page):

```
"cwd":"/home/velle/greendrinks",
```

so they obviously like the (more intuitive acronym) `cwd` over `pwd`.

I guess I am trying to figure out if I misunderstood something, or if it is just a matter of having given the environment variable an unintuitive name?

Comment: Present Work Directory?

Comment: I suspect you're just overthinking it. `$PWD` is equivalent to `\`pwd\``, and that was justification enough.

Comment: Another guess: Process Working Directory?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That depends on what you're doing.  First of all, `$PWD` is an environment variable and `pwd` is a shell builtin or an actual binary:

```
$ type -a pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
pwd is /bin/pwd
```

Now, the bash builtin will simply print the current value of `$PWD` unless you use the `-P` flag.  As explained in `help pwd`:

> `pwd: pwd [-LP]`
>
>   Print the name of the current working directory.
>
> Options:
>
>   `-L`
>       print the value of
>       `$PWD`
>       if it names the current working directory
>   `-P`
>       print the physical directory, without any symbolic links
>
> By default, ‘pwd’ behaves as if ‘-L’ were specified.

The `pwd` binary, on the other hand, gets the current directory through the [`getcwd(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) system call which returns the same value as `readlink -f /proc/self/cwd`. 
To illustrate, try moving into a directory that is a link to another one:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jun  4 11:22 foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon    4 Jun  4 11:22 linktofoo -> foo/
$ cd linktofoo
$ echo $PWD
/home/terdon/foo/linktofoo
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo/linktofoo
$ /bin/pwd
/home/terdon/foo/foo
```

So, in conclusion, on GNU systems (such as Ubuntu), `pwd` and `echo $PWD` are equivalent unless you use the `-P` option, but `/bin/pwd` is different and behaves like `pwd -P`.

**Source**
https://askubuntu.com/a/476633/291937

Comment: @llua Nothing forbids `PWD` to be an environment variable. It is actually the default case with most if not all shells and that makes sense to provide it to children processes.

Comment: So there is both a shell built-in `pwd` and a binary `/bin/pwd`, why have the latter, when the first is there?

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted, it seems like a good answer, and thoroughly explained.

Comment: @MadsSkjern Most builtins are required by the POSIX standard to be also available as commands. This is to allow calling them directly from other programs without the need to launch a shell.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question to me. The question isn't really about the differences between `$PWD` and `pwd` (which have already been covered on U&L before I believe), but about the reasons which led to naming the variable "`PWD`".

Comment: @JohnWHSmith If you downvoted for that reason which is perfectly valid, you would have better also add a comment earlier explaining why.

Comment: @jlliagre I did not, I preferred upvoting the other instead. The downvote's motives are still to be discovered :)

Comment: @jlliagre : PWD = Present Working Directory I guess

Comment: @Thushi You are more than likely correct. PWD was introduced by `ksh88` which document it as: `PWD
The present working directory set by the cd command.` You should add this to your reply.

Comment: @Thushi "the bash builtin will simply print the current value of $PWD" This is FALSE. `pwd` **always** print the **actual** working directory. A simple manual modification of the env var such as `PWD=nonsense` (without changing directory) will NOT change the output of `pwd` while `echo $PWD` will however output `nonsense`.

Answer (score 31):

`$PWD` is the **P**athname of the current **W**orking **D**irectory.

When there are symbolic links, there could be different results from reading `$PWD` compared to executing the command `pwd`.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to get different values for `$PWD` and `pwd`?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/173916/88378 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621/88378