# How does my shell know when the current working directory has been moved?

Tags: shell, directory, move, pwd

If I am in a directory `/foo`, and I move (from a different session) `/foo` to `/bar`. If I then go back to the session in `/foo` and run `ls`, the files are still there, and I can see new files if they are created there. Then I can execute `cd .` for the current working directory to be updated in the prompt and in the output of `pwd`. How does my shell know that the directory has been moved?

Comment: You may find the answers to this questions useful: [What is $PWD? (vs current working directory)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174990/what-is-pwd-vs-current-working-directory)

Comment: Is the new path `/bar/` or `/bar/foo`? In the first case it is not a move but just a rename.

Comment: The two sessions are each running in separate processes, and each session has a current directory.

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes I suppose in this case it would be a rename